# Django Custom Command with supervisorctl

Tags: python, django, supervisord

I have a Django custom management command named `Stream` that when run in a virtual environment or run using:

```
/webapps/senticle50/brexit/python-virtualenv/bin/python /webapps/senticle50/brexit/manage.py Stream --settings=brexit.settings.production
```

works but when I put the exact command into a supervisord .conf file and after running:

`supervisorctl reread && supervisorctl update`

followed by

`supervisorctl restart stream`

it starts the process but the Django command is never actually executed as no output is printed to the log file amongst other end goals of the custom Django command not being met.

**stream.conf:**

```
[program:stream]
command=/webapps/senticle50/brexit/python-virtualenv/bin/python /webapps/senticle50/brexit/manage.py Stream --settings=brexit.settings.production
user=senticle50
stdout_logfile = /webapps/senticle50/logs/stream.log   #Where to write log messages
stderr_logfile = /webapps/senticle50/logs/stream.log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
```

TLDR; The command works outside of supervisor but when run through supervisor the process starts but the command is never run.

Comment: Can you check if you have to set an environment also? `environment=ENV='production'`

Comment: @NihalSharma It doesn't seem to be required according to docs: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html and I tried inserting your fix but still no luck!